# How to execute multiple jobs in sequence via a parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile where I want to execute several commands one after the other (not in parallel).  Something like:

```
pipeline 
{
   stages
   {
        stage
        {
            steps
            { 
                sh "something PRODUCT1"
                sh "something PRODUCT2"
                sh "something PRODUCT3"
.
.
.
```

Is there a simpler syntax, where I would define all PRODUCTS in a variable, and then execute:

```
pipeline 
{
   PRODUCTS = [PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCT3]
   stages
   {
        stage
        {
            steps
            { 
                sh $PRODUCTS
.
.
.
```

?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB way to iterate over a list. But you can implement something simple.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
                    script {
                        def PRODUCTS = ["PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3"]
                        PRODUCTS.each {
                            sh"echo ${it}"
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can even create a stage per product and execute in sequence if that's your requirement.

Here is another example how you can do this with Scripted Pipeline.

```
def PRODUCTS = ["PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3"]
PRODUCTS.each { prd ->
    node {
        stage("stage $prd"){
            echo 'Product $prd'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `${it}` come from?

Comment: @Danijel that's coming from for-each loop(from Groovy). If you don't explicitly declare a variable for the loop like in the second example, groovy will let you access looped elements through `it`.

Comment: I prefer to create a stage per product. Where the `$prd` comes from?

Comment: It's again coming from the loop. `PRODUCTS.each { prd ->`  this is where you explicitly assign the loop values to a variable called `prd` without using `it`.